# Delay doesn't appear to delay after a Stop(true, true) on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

What I want is to fade in, wait 10 seconds, then fade out.  Instead, it's fading in, then immediately fading out.

It appears this code is not running at all:

```
        .delay(delayInMS)  //delayInMS is 10000 aka 10 seconds.
```

This isn't the full code base, but it is the minimal portion that causes the problem.  I need two functions with these signatures, and I don't know why the delay isn't taking place.

Code:

```
<input type="button" value="Go!">
<div>Hello!</div>
```

CSS:

```
div
{
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input').on('click', function()
    {
        showDiv();
    });
    function showDiv()
    {
        var $div = $('div');
        $div.stop(true, true)
          .fadeTo(0, 0)
          .show()
          .fadeTo(1000, 1, function()
          {
              hideDiv(10000)
          });
    }
    function hideDiv(delayInMS)
    {
        var $div = $('div');
        $div.stop(true, true)
            .delay(delayInMS)  // <-- This appears not to delay
            .fadeTo(1000, 0, function()
            {
                $div.hide();
            });
    }
});
```

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mfzgctxc/)

Comment: what you want to do???

Comment: What does the first sentence state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only work around I have is to use `setTimeout()` instead of `delay()`.  This solution is similar to 
[jmore009s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27854660/209259) but only allows a single `fadeTo()` to execute:

```
    var hideTimeout = setTimeout(void(0), 10);
    function hideDiv(delayInMS)
    {
        clearTimeout(hideTimeout);
        var $div = $('div');
        $div.stop(true, true);

        hideTimeout = setTimeout(function()
        {
            $div.fadeTo(1000, 0, function()
            {
                $div.hide();
            });
        }, delayInMS);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `.delay()` why not use `setTimeout` to handle the fade out?

```
function hideDiv(delayInMS)
  {
     var $div = $('div');
     $div.stop(true, true)
     setTimeout(function(){
        $div.fadeTo(1000, 0, function()
          {
            $div.hide();
          });
     }, delayInMS);
   }
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mfzgctxc/6/)

Comment: Good work-around, but *why* doesn't `delay` work after a `stop`? *That* is the real question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Bizarrely, the first delay after a `stop` is ignored. If you chain an extra delay the second one will work as planned:

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/mfzgctxc/2/

This is obviously not a desirable solution, so I will keep investigating :)

As you only call the hideDiv on completion of the showDiv, the `stop` in hideDiv is not actually needed, so you could revert to http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/mfzgctxc/5/ which also works.

Comment: I can't remove the `stop()` because hide may be called by some other method that may want the div to be hidden immediately.

Comment: Adding the extra delay works for delaying, but it appears to be in consistent in the duration.  In your example, the delay appears to be ~12-14 seconds for two delays @ 10.

Comment: I get 10 seconds exactly from the end of the fade-in to the start of the fade-out (using Chrome). The first delay appears to be ignored completely but has to have a large value (small ones do nothing). This is a very interesting problem you have found.

Answer (score -1):

here is

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfzgctxc/4/)

to make more delay change  `.fadeTo(5000, 50, function()` `5000` to your wish

`5000` is delay time so change the delay time as you wish

Comment: I am not looking to delay the time it takes to fade, I'm trying to delay the time between the fades.

Comment: so when you click go button `div` should open delayed time

Comment: What should happen, FadeIn 1 second, Delay 10 seconds, FadeOut 1 second. Instead the delay is ZERO seconds.

Comment: @ErikPhilips check out fiddle now

Comment: Delaying the fadeIn, by going past a value of 1 (to opacity 50), just to avoid the problem is not a solution (but nice try).